# Minutiae Point Extraction from Fingerprints using Java Code

Tags: java, fingerprint, biometrics

I am developing a Java program that uses the fingerprints from a user as input for generating keys for encryption and digital signature. For this purpose, I want to get the **minutiae points** from the fingerprint and use the extracted minutiae points to create a **unique key**.

Also, I want this algorithm to be accurate enough so that I should be able to get the exact minutiae points and be able to recreate the same exact unique key when the same fingerprint is introduced to the system again and again.

Can anyone be able to help me with the Java code for extracting minutiae points from the fingerprint?

And I'm using "SecuGen Hamster Plus" device for acquiring the user's fingerprint!

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Use getTemplate() method to get minutae points from finger print in form of bye array

You can also use setTemplateFormat() method to set template format into one of the following
ISO format
Ansi format
Secugens own format